# How to sell excess electronic components for highest price with least effort

Tags: components

This question relates to Electrical Engineering with respect to the management of spare electronics parts after a production build of circuit boards.  This question is specifically not being asked on economics.stackexchange because I believe the best answer would be created by people in the electronics industry with direct experience in dealing with excess parts (rather than an answer based on general economics/business principles).

I have a reel containing 487 opto-isolators of part number G3VM-61ER that never got used.  I was hoping to sell them rather than throw them away.  I am not trying to sell them here, I just want to ask what the best way in general will be to sell them somewhere.

My objective criteria for "best" is that I get the maximum amount of money for the parts without spending a lot of time managing a lot of small transactions.  For the purposes of this question "small transactions" would be defined as under $100 each.  "Lots of transactions" would be defined as more than 20 separate sales.  Ideally I should not spend more than 20 hours total related to the sale.  All transactions should be completed within one year.

The parts were purchased from an authorized distributor and I have the original paperwork that shipped with the parts.  The parts are stored in their original packaging and were purchased less than one year ago.

**Given the above, I was wondering what the best way to sell these spare electronic parts?**

I see the following options so far.

1)  My research shows that these parts sell for about $20 each on e-bay or amazon.  It would be great if I could make that work because my total sale would be around $10,000.  The problem is that buyers on those sites would probably be people who just need one part to repair something (rather than a product manufacturer who wants to buy the whole reel).  My time is valuable and I could easily see myself wasting $10,000 worth of my time selling the parts a handful at a time.

2)  I have found several chip brokers online that would probably buy the parts.  Some examples include Online Components, Jameco, Quest Components, 4-Star Electronics, Chip 1 Exchange.  I could probably get one of them to buy the whole reel.  The only downside is that they will probably only pay 5 to 10% their actual value.  The price from the authorized distributors (Digi-key, Mouser, Avnet, etc.) is around $10 each for one and $6.00 each for 500.  That puts the resale value of my reel at about $2900.  Which means the chip brokers probably won't give me more than $150 to $300 for it.

3)  I could Design the opto-isolators into a new product.  Rather than getting money for the parts I could use them and avoid having to buy parts for another build.  The only downside is that I only have a limited amount of parts and these are fairly expensive opto-isolators.  If I need more than the 487 I have on-hand I would find myself forced locked into using this expensive part.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100629/discussion-on-question-by-user4574-how-to-sell-excess-electronic-components-for).

Comment: @Huisman I contacted several brokers and the magic word I was looking for was "consignment".  Part brokers who take consignment parts will go through the trouble advertising, selling, and shipping parts for a cut of the proceeds.  The brokers I contacted wanted between 20% to 50% of the sale value.  They typically try to sell the parts at full market value so the seller can get 50% to 80% of market value without having to do anything other than give them to the broker under a consignment contract.  Outright sale gets you money immediately, but you may only get about 10% of market value.